# My Application doesn't show option menu button

Tags: android, optionmenu

I am using an X-TREME 7' tablet running Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) as a test device. After installing my application on this tablet I can't see the menu button on the screen. However, when I test the same application on an emulator running Gingerbread(2.3.3) and I press the F2 button, the option menu pops up.

Does anyone know what the problem is caused by and have a solution to it?

My project's manifest includes:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you're developing for Android 2.3 or lower, users can reveal the
>   options menu panel by pressing the Menu button. On Android 3.0 and
>   higher, items from the options menu are presented by the action bar as
>   a combination of on-screen action items and overflow options.
>   Beginning with Android 3.0, the Menu button is deprecated (some
>   devices don't have one), so you should migrate toward using the action
>   bar to provide access to actions and other options.

Source : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow this for menu button android version > 3.0

`1. Android no longer requires a dedicated Menu button, some devices don’t have one, and you should migrate away from using it.1`

`2. Set targetSdkVersion to 14, then test your app on Android 4.0.`

`3.Add showAsAction="ifRoom" to menu items you’d like to surface in the action bar.`

`4.If the ActionBar doesn’t work for your app, you can remove it with Theme.Holo.NoActionBar or Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.`

Beautiful Article from Andoid Blog, [**Say Good Bye to the Menu Button**](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)

Comment: @ kumar_android i didn't understand the 3rd step.